# How to convert datatime.now to only date?

Tags: python, django

How to convert datatime.now to only date?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

now = datetime.now()
#2013-01-16 15:46:00.310499
```

I need only date, without time

Comment: You could have just plugged this into Google and found it out faster than typing it here and waiting for a response. Marking it down for not showing any research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`.date()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) on it:

```
datetime.now().date()
```

or just use [`date.today()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) instead:

```
from datetime import date
date.today()
```